# TV Guide Automatically Scroll Horizontally to Current Time

Tags: jquery, html, date, time, scroll

I am hoping there is someone out there who can help me.. I have a TV guide currently in DIV's. How do companies such as free-view/sky set the guide to start at the current time?

I.E. Time is now 7pm, therefore the following should be outputted:

<| 7pm | 8pm | 9pm | 10pm |>

<|show | show| show| show |>

I have spent a lot of time googling things such as current time scroll div and all combinations. Not exacty sure what this feature is called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean? You may want to explain to everyone what you are trying to do and give code that you have tried and examples.

Comment: Sorry for not making this more clear, I have set up the following jsfiddle in my site http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/1136/. Each of the green boxes have a value in them - 9am, 10am, 11am etc. How to get the first div on the left to start at the current time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the time :

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours();
```

Next find the div with that time :

```
var myDiv = $("mycontainer").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(time) > -1;
});
```

Next Scroll to that div

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: myDiv.offset().top
}, 2000);
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mathieu, don't really understand that. Are you aware of any online tutorials or anything that I could use? Or what it is I should be searching for to help with this?

Comment: well, it's just global jquery skills. Once you get familiar with manipulating the DOM, the only limitation is your imagination. I don't know any tutorial for jquery, i just learn it will working.